# Ways to select background-image "ONLY" in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I set up in jQuery to give scale property on background-image 'only' but the div keeps getting big itself. Like this:[image]

This is how I set up in jQuery and HTML.

```js
var bg = $('.news_box_long').css('background-image', 'img/img_09.jpg')
  $('.news_box_long').mouseenter(function(){
    if(!$(bg).is(':animated')) {
      $(this).css({'transform': 'scale('+ 1.1 +')'})
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="news_box_long background" style="background-image: url(img/img_09.jpg)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. CSS would be quite enough

```css
.news_box_long {
  height: 200px;
}

.background {
  background: 50% 50%/100% none no-repeat;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.background:hover {
  background-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="news_box_long background" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9f/1f/f5/9f1ff5f730db75ce458ee2890b8e6197.jpg)">
</div>
```

Comment: lol  I didn't know CSS would work this. Thanks for answering.